# Taking user input in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am using apex from oracle for learning PL/SQL for last 10 days. At a sudden, I wrote a code to take some inputs from user.
`

```
declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := &x;
  dbms_output.put_line(a*6);  
end;
```

`
it is throwing some errors.>>ORA-06550

I am expected to take user input from it. As Pl/sql is not that famous, there are very li'l stuffs available about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, it works:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    a number;
  3  begin
  4    a := &x;
  5    dbms_output.put_line(a*6);
  6  end;
  7  /
Enter value for x: 4
old   4:   a := &x;
new   4:   a := 4;
24

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

But, in **Apex workshop**, you can't use a substitution, but a **bind** variable:

```
declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := :x;                             --> this
  dbms_output.put_line(a*6);  
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct. Below I'm running it from the sqlcl command prompt. Note that you can only accept user input if you run the code in a sql environment.

```
koen >set serveroutput on 
koen >declare 
  2    a number;
  3  begin
  4    a := &x;
  5    dbms_output.put_line(a*6);  
  6  end;    
  7* /
Enter value for x: 5
old:declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := &x;
  dbms_output.put_line(a*6);  
end;

new:declare 
  a number;
begin
  a := 5;
  dbms_output.put_line(a*6);  
end;
30


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

koen >
```